# Excel Formula for payroll

Tags: excel

I need two formulas for payroll. I have 7 cells that I enter the daily labor hours, and in a "total" cell I want to have a total of the payroll hours not to exceed 40 (when I enter B3:H3), and IF the total of the payroll hours DOES exceed 40 I want the rest of the hours to go on the "OT" cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you attempted anything or are you looking for someone to just provide you a solution?

Comment: Great! I'd bet `SUMIF()`/`SUMIFS()` is what you need.

Comment: Hi Karina and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please note that questions without an actual question in them are off-topic here, and liable to be down-voted and closed.  Can you show us what you've attempted to do to solve this yourself, and what specific problem you've encountered?  Please also review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help section of the site.

Answer (score 1):

In the total cell put:

```
=MIN(40, SUM(B3:H3))
```

In the OT cell put:

```
=MAX(0, SUM(B3:H3)-40)
```